# MKMapView and locationManager always returns 0,0 nomatter how I do it

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I tried about 100 different solutions and still locationManager always returns coordinates 0,0.

and... never ever, not once has it ever called the didUpdateLocations:

I found a code that makes sure everything on the phone is turned on properly... still nothing.

Can I do something wrong that is unrelated to the source code?

My latest attempt uses a button that setts the whole thing in motion, but as I said.. still 0,0.. it zooms in and mover to that location perfectly.

Whats going on.. does locations don't work on iPhone 4s with the latest software or something?

### Some code that don't work....

### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import<CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface TestingMapsFirstViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,      CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *locationButton;
property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *test1;
property (weak, nonatomic) CLLocation *CURRENT_LOCATION;
end
```

### .m

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
[self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[self.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[super viewDidLoad];
 }


- (void)startUpdatingCurrentLocation
{
// if location services are on
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    // if location services are restricted do nothing
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted )
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Determining your current location cannot be performed at this time because location services are enabled but restricted." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
    {


        if(!self.locationManager)
        {
            self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            self.locationManager.delegate = self;
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
            self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

          //  [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:5.0f];          // measured in meters
          //  [_locationManager setHeadingFilter:5];              // measured in degrees

            self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.locationManager.location.coordinate;//self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;
          //  [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate zoomLevel:2.0 animated:YES];

            NSLog(@"user latitude = %f",_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude);
            NSLog(@"user longitude = %f",_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
        }

        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Determining your current location cannot be performed at this time because location services are not enabled." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}

// Delegate method
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
CLLocation* loc = [locations lastObject]; // locations is guaranteed to have at least one object
float latitude = loc.coordinate.latitude;
float longitude = loc.coordinate.longitude;
NSLog(@"%.8f",latitude);
NSLog(@"%.8f",longitude);
}
```

I would realy appreciate an answer to my problem, feels I tried everything here and is at the end of my rope.

Comment: What gets printed in `...didUpdateLocations:`?

Comment: You should not expect location to be available immediately after calling startUpdatingLocation.  You must use the didUpdateLocations delegate method (or the MKMapView's didUpdateUserLocation).  If the `didUpdateLocations:` method is not getting called, also implement `didFailWithError` and see what the error is, if any.  Also, in the Simulator menu, while the app is running, you can go to Debug -> Location and try Freeway Drive -- it should start sending simulated location updates.

Comment: didFailWithError or didUpdateLocations: is never triggered and i don't get any visible indication to why.

Comment: freeway selection does nothing, it just as in all simulations always start at the united states and if I press the button I have made, it goes to coordinates 0,0

Comment: To answer Carl Veazey... it doesn't print anything.. the code never gets there.. it just refuses to trigger anything.  I have never managed to get any location trigger to run for any reason and that include the didfail.. one.

Comment: It looks to me that there is something non code thing I am missing here... what else besides that code do I need for it to work?

Comment: The code you posted works for me.  I suggest you download a sample app from the Apple Dev site that uses CLLocatioManager such as "Geocoder" and run that.  You're testing on iOS 6 or iOS 7, right?

Comment: Where are you calling `-[TestingMapsFirstViewController startUpdatingCurrentLocation]` from? Also you might have some confusion with your properties and ivars going on, you have declared an ivar `locationManager` in your header, yet call methods on `_locationManager`, so I'm assuming you are using automatic property synthesis? Finally, just to verify, when you set a breakpoint at the line `self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];` you do indeed reach it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code, though a bit messy.. scroll down to see the proof. Is the delegate is not called then by some reason **you haven't allowed the app to use location services**. Go to Settings/Privacy/LocationService and find your app to allow location services. It looks like this:

[image: locationServices]

Here's the proof of working code:

[image: proofWorkingCode]

-- edit
And make sure to import the CoreLocation and Mapkit framework to your project like this:

[image: framework]

Comment: I checked my phone for that, but my app don't appear in that list in the settings.

Comment: I edited my answer, did you add the CoreLocation and Mapkit Framework to your project?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code from this site, created a new app and pasted the code in.. and it worked imedieltly... So problem solved.

Thanks for the effort.